# .netcore web application failing with 'buffer supplied to a function was too small' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-framework-version, system.net

I have a web application running which basically calls 3 very basic API that retrieve data from a 3rd party, save it in a json file and load this data for further processing.

At first, the web application was working fine, however as time went by I started noticing the following error occurring intermettently:

> *System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. --->
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication
> failed, see inner exception. --->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The buffers supplied to a
> function was too small --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo
> exception) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest
> asyncRequest) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
> exception was thrown --- at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional() at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
> lazyResult) at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult
> result) at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.b__47_1(IAsyncResult
> iar) at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
> requiresSynchronization) --- End of stack trace from previous location
> where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream
> stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream
> stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask,
> HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
> disposeCts) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest() at
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()*

I've searched the internet high and low and haven't been able to find a fix for this. I've also recently updated the .netcore sdk version to 2.1.105 and Microsoft.NetCore.APP/Microsoft.ASPNetCore.All as I read somewhere that the error should occur less frequently. The complete opposite happened.

Comment: If this was a .NET problem you'd get errors every time. `intermettently` suggests this is a network problem. Network failures are *guaranteed*, no matter what language or platform is used. If a dog chews your network cable, you'll lose packets and connections until your WiFi picks up.

Comment: The only thing you can do when an HTTP call fails is to retry it. Both server and client code must be written to handle retries. At least on the client side you can use libraries like `Polly` to automatically retry with varying delays before retries. [Implement HTTP call retries with exponential backoff with IHttpClientFactory and Polly policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly) shows how HttpClient and Polly cooperate to retry in case of errors

Comment: It's not just network errors either. Perhaps the server crashed and you have to connect to another one? Perhaps the server throttled you? Perhaps a service is down so you need to use an alternative? [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) uses various policies to handle different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue before as well. After digging through GitHub issues and various reproductions, it looks like it's probably caused by malformed TLS packets due to network instability. Since it's a framework issue all you can do is try to catch the error and retry, and hope it's fixed someday.

Comment: You wrote it's a network issue. The framework can't fix broken packets. The only solution is to try and connect again. Retrying is the job of resiliency libraries like Polly